# SaveTokens = true stupid in OpenIdConnect Middleware?

Tags: identityserver4

After getting the access token with hybrid or authorization code flow to keep them from the browser it seems stupid to use SaveTokens = true in the (ASP.NET Core) OpenIdConnect middleware so that they end up in the browser again.

What is a better way to store the access token using the middleware?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `SaveTokens` the middleware stores the tokens in the cookie along with a users claims. Whilst this cookie might be stored in a browser it's protected so only that application can read it. The browser or client side code cannot read the cookie. So they're not really ending up in the browser (like they would using the implicit grant type).

Otherwise what you would need to do is create a token store, looking up tokens either by authenticated user or by session.

ASP.NET Core Identity has a table for storing tokens for a user you could look into using, but then this would mean all of your applications have to integrate with the ASP.NET Identity library and a token could be accessed by any app.

Comment: Or you could implement the ticket cache in the cookie MW - and keep all data on the server.

Comment: I noted that Dominick Baier says (around the 46:10 mark of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXdJ2HLAOdE ... NDC 2017 London IdentityServer4 presentation) that setting SaveTokens = True is not a good idea for other reasons involving cookies getting too large. ...And now I think of it... isn't he leastprivilege?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of key differences compared to the implicit flow which makes this significantly more secure:

1. They end up in the browser as [`Secure` and `HttpOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Restrict_access_to_cookies) cookies, which means they are:

   1. Only sent over encrypted requests over HTTPS.
   2. They are inaccessible to JavaScript.
2. The cookies are encrypted as well, and can only be read by the ASP.NET Core server app. So even if an attacker does somehow obtain them, to decrypt them they'd need access to the server, or the encryption key used by ASP.NET Core's Data Protection provider.